# How can I check whether a value is present in the neighbors of a Graph node?

Tags: python, networkx

I can check whether a value is present in the attributes of all nodes in a Graph:

```py
G = nx.star_graph(4)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {0:{"x":"a"}, 1:{"x":"b"}, 3:{"x":"a"}, 4:{"x":"b"}})
print(G.nodes(data = "x"))
# [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, None), (3, 'a'), (4, 'b')]

print("a" in dict(G.nodes(data = "x")).values())
# True

print("c" in dict(G.nodes(data = "x")).values())
# False
```

Now I would like to check whether the value of the `"x"` attribute is present in any of the *neighbors* of a node, e.g. node `0` or node `1`.

I can't figure out how to do this with the common ways of accessing a nodes neighbors. I'm imagining something like `G[n].nodes(data = "x")`, but `G[n]` returns an AtlasView which can't (as far as I can tell) access the neighbors data.

`G.neighbors(n)` returns an iterator. I could just use this iterator and step through inspecting the data of each node. I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that this would be less efficient than inspecting all nodes' data "at once", as demonstrated above for the entire graph.

The answer does not have to follow the direction I have in mind, especially if a proposed answer is faster or more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Given the answer to a similar question here: [networkx search for a node by attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447951/networkx-search-for-a-node-by-attributes)

I'd say an answer to this might look like this:

```py
>>> [y for y in [x for x in G[0]] if 'x' in G.node[y]]
[1, 3, 4]
>>> [y for y in [x for x in G[0]] if 'x' in G.node[y] and G.node[y]['x']=='a']
[3]
>>> [y for y in [x for x in G[0]] if 'x' in G.node[y] and G.node[y]['x']=='c']
[]
>>> [y for y in [x for x in G[0]] if 'x' in G.node[y] and G.node[y]['x']=='b']
[1, 4]
```

I dunno how 'pythonic' it is,  but there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to access the neighbors having some criteria.